# How to add Likes without asking user for Authentication?

Tags: django

I have a pretty simple Django app for quotes. I want to add likes to every single quote but I don't want user to login for that.
How can I achieve this without Logging in the user?

I tried to uniquely identify users without logging in.

Comment: You can't really reliably uniquely identify users. You could store a cookie that stores whether a user added a like, but cookies can be deleted. You could use the ip address, but ip addresses change and many users might share an ip address.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm kinda stuck with this I think I'll try the IP address method.